# Differentiate clipboard event when using read() function in c from stdin

Tags: c, clipboard, stdin, differentiation

I am working on terminal based text editor and stuck at a point where I need to differentiate whether the input text from read() function is a clipboard paste text or a keyboard text input.

```
#include <unistd.h>

char read_key_input() {
    char ch;
    int read_count;

    while ((read_count = read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1)) != 1)
    {
        // Handle error if any
    }
    
    return ch;
}

...
```

Edit: Here's what I ended up doing.

```
void read_key_input(void (*callback)(int)) {
    char* text = malloc(UINT8_MAX);
    int read_count;

    while ((read_count = read(STDIN_FILENO, text, UINT8_MAX)) == -1)
    {
        // Handle error if any
    }

    // Handle escape sequences if found and return early
    ...

    if (read_count > 1) {
        // It's probably a clipboard text. So change the editor mode to input and loop through all the characters one by one.
    else {
        // It's a user keyboard text input
    }

    // Revert back to the original editor mode if changed
}
```

I updated the code to retrieve more than one byte at a time (as suggested by @AnttiHaapala) and process each byte. Seems to be sufficient for my text editor's need for now. Will post back if I update.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can differentiate this by counting the number of characters you've received in rapid succession. So if you get the keypresses more rapidly than say 1000 characters per minute, then it is likely a clipboard paste... or nonsense.

Furthermore, if you've set the terminal to raw mode, then you can easily monitor individual keypresses. Also make `read` accept *more* than one byte at once - with `read` that is the *maximum* number of bytes to receive without blocking when available anyway.

---

One example of such an interactive terminal program would be IPython - here two lines typed separately:

```
In [1]: print("Hello")
Hello

In [2]: print("World")
World
```

And here pasted in one go:

```
In [3]: print("Hello")
   ...: print("World")
   ...:
Hello
World
```

Notice how the prompt is different, and the program runs only after there has been a separate Enter key hit after a small delay.

Comment: Is that the only option? 'Cause I wanna have quick double key press functionality as well in the editor I'm working on. That might lead in a multiple time difference comparison I guess e.g. time_between_input < 50 ms ? Clipboard text :  User input

Comment: Sorry it this question is out of context, but do you know how do other text editors like vim or ncurses library differentiate?

Comment: @JitenDevlani you cannot tell quick double key press apart from 2 characters copy-pasted, but would you *care*. A copy paste would be a significant piece of text. The only case where you would probably care is if you were programming a game like "typespeed" and trying to make sure that the player does not cheat with copy paste

Comment: I think I do have to take this into consideration as well, my text editor supports different modes (Normal, Insert, Visual) just like vim. And I don't want it to execute a command say `jump to text` (which might be bound to a key combination <jc>) when the user pastes from clipboard. It should always be in input mode when the text comes from clipboard

Comment: `just like vim` Then maybe real life example - https://github.com/roxma/vim-paste-easy is a vim plugin, that if the time between typed characters is lower then 10ms, it changes vim settings.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot do what you want (reliably).

The clipboard is related (usually) to some display server, e.g. [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorg) or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) server (Weston). And X11 might have *distant* clients (hence, a clipboard operation could be slow, if crossing some ocean).

Some Linux machines (perhaps the web server at Stackoverflow) do not run any display server.

You could code a GUI application, e.g. using [GTK](https://gtk.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/).

You could test if your standard input is a terminal with [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) functions or [isatty(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) (i.e. with `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` or `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)` for standard output)

If your program is run inside a [crontab(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) job, or a [unix pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), the standard input won't be a terminal, and there might not even be any display server running.

You could take inspiration from the source code of [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), which does detect when a display server is available (probably using [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), e.g. [getenv(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) of `"DISPLAY"`...)

On Linux you might [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) `/dev/tty` (see [tty(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)) to access your terminal. In some cases, it does not exist.

Comment: Do I have to check whether the standard input is a terminal If I have put the terminal into raw mode? If yes how do I do that? isatty(STDIN_FILENO)?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @jiten not sure if you checked like
its key input detect and check wether it's input is one by one key
or its instant bulk input.